# iphone web app ignores cookies when added to home screen

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I have a mobile web app that uses cookies to keep a user logged in. Works fine in safari but when added to the home screen this is ignored, making users log in every time they start the app. Anyway around this?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a promising solution: http://rubygems.org/gems/rack_iphone_web_app